# How can I see the container I am working with in React Native styling?

Tags: css, react-native, styling

I want to be able to create a border or a add color to see the rectangular "view" or "container" that I have items with. Is there any way I can do this? Visualizing the container helps me see what's going on when I am styling in React or CSS.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/style